# Is it possible to mention people in a status update via the Linkedin AP v2I?

Tags: linkedin-api

I need to tag a company/person in a LinkedIn post which is generated by code when I use the @name in the string which is posted to Linkedin then the post turns out to just pain text and not a tag to which the person is informed.

Comment: Is it possible to mention people in a status update via the Linkedin AP v2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to mention organisations or people within a share. You can do this by adding the annotations parameter for every organisation or person you want to mention. For example:

```
{
    "annotations": [
        {
            "entity": "urn:li:organization:1337",
            "length": 8,
            "start": 6
        }
    ],
    "text": "Hello LinkedIn world!"
}
```

You can read more about sharing an update and mentioning in the LinkedIn doc's here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api#share-text-and-mentions.